# asp.net web forms app doesn't build on "start with debugging"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a small asp.net app running in the vs.net web server that doesn't always build when I start the site with debugging.  The previous build just comes up in the browser, any breakpoints are ignored.  What is the issue?  I don't recall seeing this in any of the other sites I work with.  If I do a rebuild enough times it eventually works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Configuration Manager and ensure that the website is selected to be 'built' in the current configuration.

Comment: When you say "that" configuration, which one do you mean? How can you check that you're in the proper config?

Comment: That was it! Thanks.  My solution had three projects.  Build was not selected in the Config Manager for the one I'm  working with at the moment.

Comment: @Sterno Updated for clarification. Thanks